# Rails run object method on itself periodically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I need to run a method once daily in a Rails application.

I'm thinking about using the whenever gem, but I realize I have a bit of a problem.

I need to run the method on an instance of an object. So I can't just have something like:

```
every 1.day do
    runner 'Object.method'
end
```

I'm thinking about doing something like

```
every 1.day do
  runner 'Object.where(status: "the_status_i_want").each { |object| object.method }'
end
```

But I have no clue how to test this behavior from within 'whenever.'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates has a nice episode on integrating whenever gem into Rails

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

(There is also a free version on that site, but it's kinda old, http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby)